# How do I stop paintEvent from painting children widgets?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qdialog, paintevent

I'm trying to add rounded corners to a `QDialog`.  I'm defining my own `paintEvent` method to create rounded corners.  It's working, but it's adding rounded borders to everything.  Even the cursor is getting a border.  Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Example code:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class RenameDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(RenameDialog, self).__init__(
            parent=parent, f=QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
        self.fieldA = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.fieldB = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

        self.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.fieldA)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.fieldB)

        # Set background transparent.  Only items drawn in paintEvent
        # will be visible.
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        fillColor = QtGui.QColor(75, 75, 75, 255)
        lineColor = QtCore.Qt.gray

        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QBrush(lineColor), 2.0))
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(fillColor))
        painter.drawRoundedRect(event.rect(), 15, 15)
```

I'm trying to do this with a `paintEvent` because:

- QDialog stylesheets cannot use `border-radius`.  Curved borders do show up, but corners are still visible.
- `QDialogs.setMask()` works, but there is no way (that I know of) to anti-alias the mask.

Here is what that looks like:

[image: borders everywhere]

Comment: Got a screenshot? "Adding rounded borders to everything" sounds weird.

Comment: It is weird.  I added a screenshot.  The borders on the second field don't appear until I focus that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paint events are sent to a window/widget with the precise rectangle that needs updating not the whole bounding rectangle of the widget. When you call `event.rect()` it returns the rectangle that needs updating (As far as I know)

Try changing this line
    `painter.drawRoundedRect(event.rect(), 15, 15)`
To this
    `painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 15, 15)`

**EDIT:**
You also need to add this line anywhere in the constructor
`self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah!  That makes perfect sense.  Thanks!  Oh, and I'm setting CustomizeWindowHint in the example - which is doing the same thing as FramelessWindowHint on my system (KDE).  Maybe it behaves slightly different on other window managers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-around for now.  You can hide the extra borders by using `QPainter.eraseRect` on the children and having the correct stylesheet set. I've also found that painting over the offending area with `QPainter.fillRect` works too.

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    fillColor = QtGui.QColor(75, 75, 75, 255)
    lineColor = QtCore.Qt.gray

    painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QBrush(lineColor), 2.0))
    painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(fillColor))
    painter.drawRoundedRect(event.rect(), 15, 15)

    # Sketchy fix:
    painter.eraseRect(self.childrenRect())
    # OR
    painter.fillRect(self.childrenRect(), QtGui.QBrush(fillColor))
```

This doesn't answer my original question though.  I'd like to avoid this behavior rather than masking it.  So I'm not going to mark this as the answer.